# Cannot find definitions of editor-label and editor-field in MVC 4, did MS remove it? Why?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

While I used to work with MVC 3, I took some portions of my previous project and embedding them into new MVC 4 template. Apparently the two most used CSS class definitions `editor-label` and `editor-field` in divs have disappeared from Site.css in MVC 4.

The question is should I define them back in the CSS file or use something else or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are a couple of options you can take:

### Wrap the elements in a class

Wrap all your inputs in a `div` and change your styles to target that `div` instead of `.editor-label` and `.editor-field`.

So HTML

```
<label class="editor-label">blah</label>
<input class="editor-field" />
```

Becomes

```
<div class="editor">
    <label class="editor-label">blah</label>
    <input class="editor-field" />
</div>
```

And your CSS

```
.editor-label { /**/ }
.editor-field { /**/ }
```

Becomes

```
.editor label { /**/ }
.editor input,
.editor select { /**/ }
```

### Add them back with JavaScript

You may be able to get away with using some JavaScript to add the classes back in.

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/MDaZm/)

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var labels = content.getElementsByTagName('label');

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].classList.add('editor-label');
    var id = labels[i].getAttribute('for');
    var input = document.getElementById(id);
    input.classList.add('editor-field');
}
```

### Modify the editor templates

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) on how to modify display and editor templates a few months ago allowing custom HTML to be output from `HtmlHelper.EditorFor()` and `HtmlHelper.DisplayFor()`. This would allow you to put the classes back in where they were. This method may be more trouble than it's worth for your situation though.

Basically you can place a custom view in at the location `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` named based on the type you want to override, for example `string.cshtml` for `string`. An example view for `string` could be:

**string.cshtml**

```
@model string

@{
    var id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(Model);
}

<label class="editor-label" for="@id"></label>
<input type="text" class="editor-field" id="@id" />
```

### Pass in `htmlAttributes`

You can't pass in a class to the htmlAttributes argument on `EditorFor()`, but you can for `LabelFor()` and `TextBoxFor()`, etc. You could change all instances of `EditorFor()` to their respective types and provide the classes in the call.

```
@Html.LabelFor(e => e.UserName, new { @class="editor-field" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class="editor-field" })
```

### Further reading

- [My blog post - ASP.NET MVC display and editor templates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive response. Can you tell why MS would remove it from MVC 3 to MVC 4? Since people presumably built projects using MVC 3 and migrating to MVC 4, why did it just dissapear? I understand it can be recovered, but if its so ubiquitous, why would they remove it?

Comment: Well I can't tell you why they removed it, only they can tell you that. I assume it's because it was kind of forcing people in to using classes that weren't particularly nice. Keep in mind it's a major version 3 -> 4 and you should expect some breaking changes like this.