# Standard MVC4 project's Site.css does not contain definition for display-label, editor-label, editor-field

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a new project / solution in VS2012 (Premium, Update 2) and select the `ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application` template. The Site.css that's created in the Content folder does not contain definitions for `display-label`, `editor-label`, `editor-field` and more. But when I let VS2012 create a new View, it creates a view that uses those classes.

Is this normal behavior? Or is something wrong with my installation of VS2012?

If I create a new `ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application` the Site.css *does* contain the definitions.

I believe the new project content is coming from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev4.1.cshtml\Content`. The Site.css file in that folder on my computer is dated 2/19/2013 12:36 and has a size of 13.944 bytes. Is it different on your computer?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586733/cannot-find-definitions-of-editor-label-and-editor-field-in-mvc-4-did-ms-remove) that seems similar, but in that situation code from an MVC3 application was migrated to MVC4. In my situation I'm just creating an out of the box new MVC4 application.

Comment: I just created a brand new MVC 4 app from VS 2012, and it had all the css in it. Which template did you select? (Empty/Basic/Internet application). I also have update 2 for VS2012 not sure that it matters.

Comment: I've created a ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application, then selected Internet Application, and I'm using the Razor view engine. I've also tried the ASPX view engine, but no lock. Are you saying your Site.css *does* have a definition for `display-label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an answer that helps particularly, but it does seem that what you've seen is expected behaviour. I've just created projects in both VS2010 and VS2012 in MVC3 and MVC4 and it does seem that the styles of those classes have been removed from MVC4, probably because their initial styling was simply this :

```
.display-label, 
.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.display-field, 
.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}
```

It doesn't hurt to have classes with no styles automatically added to those elements, but it does provide a default hook for you to apply your own styles, that's probably the reason they left them in.

Sadly, this isn't something mentioned in the [release notes for ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes).

Comment: What puzzles me is that Jay sais (in his comment on my post) that when he creates a new MVC4 applicati it *does* have all the css.

Comment: I don't think I believe him. My project templates don't have those styles in and a little Googling suggests this is a common surprise for people moving from mvc3 to mvc4.