# In MVC 4 using Razor not finding the class in the default css(site.css) provided by Microsoft for changing the style of textbox and dropdown

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have used the default(Razor-cshtml) template provided by the Microsoft to insert the data in db using MVC.It is working fine.
Now i have added three new drop-down lists for which i want to apply same look and feel as that of text-box.(Width and style of textbox and dropdown should be same).

Microsoft used div class="editor-field and editor-label" for text-boxes(EditorFor) and labels.But this is not applying for DropdownlistFor.Why is it so??

I even want to change the style like: width and font of textbox.How to do it??

I searched these classes in the default css(site.css) provided by Microsoft,But i'm not finding these classes.How to solve this???

How to make the Uniform css for all the textbox and dropdownlist using default css(site.css) provided by microsoft.

Please suggest me some ways to do it.

My CSHTML Code:

```
@model Sample.Models.Master.CompanyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CompanyModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.CompanyID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyModel.CompanyID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.CompanyID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyModel.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.Address1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyModel.Address1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.Address1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.Address2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyModel.Address2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.Address2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.Address3)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyModel.Address3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.Address3)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.CountryID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.companyModel.CountryID,Model.ddlCompanyModel.ddlCountry,"Select Country")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.CountryID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.StateID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.companyModel.StateID,Model.ddlCompanyModel.ddlState,"Select State")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.StateID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.CityID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.companyModel.CityID,Model.ddlCompanyModel.ddlCity,"Select City")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.CityID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.Pin)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyModel.Pin)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.Pin)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyModel.Phone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.companyModel.Phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyModel.Phone)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Default CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:link, a:visited,
    a:active, a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

    a:hover {
        background-color: #c7d1d6;
    }

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}
.sidebar {
    background-color:#efeeef;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}

#body {
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    clear: both;
    /*padding-bottom: 35px;*/
}

    .main-content {
        /*background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;*/
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .featured + .main-content {
        /*background: url("../Images/heroAccent.png") no-repeat;*/
    }

header .content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 30px; 
    padding-bottom:60px;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.username {
        background: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


/* left-menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#left-menu {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    /*margin: 0 0 5px;*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

    ul#left-menu li {
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 18px;
    }

        ul#left-menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#left-menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* featured */
.featured {
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        background-color: #7ac0da;
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        color: #3e5667;
        padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
    }

        .featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
            color: #fff;
        }

        .featured p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

/* page titles */
hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ol.round li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        padding-left: 45px;
    }

        ol.round li.zero {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.one {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.two {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.three {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.four {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.five {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.six {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.seven {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.eight {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.nine {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
        }

/* content */
article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

    aside ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

        aside ul li {
            background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
            padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
        }

.label {
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* login page */
#loginForm {
    border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}

    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #loginForm input {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #loginForm input[type="checkbox"],
    #loginForm input[type="submit"],
    #loginForm input[type="button"],
    #loginForm button {
        width: auto;
    }

#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

    #socialLoginForm h2 {
        margin-bottom:  5px;
    }

#socialLoginList button {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#logoutForm {
    display: inline;
}

/* contact */
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

/* forms */
fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    fieldset legend {
        display: none;
    }

    fieldset ol {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        fieldset ol li {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

label.checkbox {
    display: inline;
}

input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 500px;
}

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"] {
        background: transparent;
        border: inherit;
        width: auto;
    }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}


/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    th a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    th.asc a, th.desc a {
        margin-right: .75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0em;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after {
        content: '▲';
    }

    th.desc a:after {
        content: '▼';
    }

td {
    padding: 0.25em 0.25em 0.25em 0.5em;
    border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}


/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left,
    header .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #login ul {
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a:hover {
            color: #333;
        }

    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-content,
    .featured + .main-content {
        background-position: 10px 0;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /* page content */
    article, aside {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* ordered list */
    ol.round {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

        ol.round li {
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 25px 0;
        }

            ol.round li.zero,
            ol.round li.one,
            ol.round li.two,
            ol.round li.three,
            ol.round li.four,
            ol.round li.five,
            ol.round li.six,
            ol.round li.seven,
            ol.round li.eight,
            ol.round li.nine {
                background: none;
            }

     /* features */
     section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
     }

        section.feature img {
            color: #999;
            content: attr(alt);
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }

    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

        #loginForm .validation-error {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left,
    footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0 0;
    }

        footer p {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586733/cannot-find-definitions-of-editor-label-and-editor-field-in-mvc-4-did-ms-remove) by **Daniel Imms** says

I need to wrap the elements in class as:

**HTML as:**

```
<div class="editor">
    <label class="editor-label">Test</label>
    <input class="editor-field" />
</div>
```

**Instead of:**

```
<label class="editor-label">Test</label>
<input class="editor-field" />
```

**CSS as:**

```
.editor label { /**/ }
.editor input,
.editor select { /**/ }
```

**Instead of:**

```
.editor-label { /**/ }
.editor-field { /**/ }
```

**We may use some javascript to add the classes back in:**

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var labels = content.getElementsByTagName('label');

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].classList.add('editor-label');
    var id = labels[i].getAttribute('for');
    var input = document.getElementById(id);
    input.classList.add('editor-field');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like below..

```
.cssclass{
width:auto!important;
}
```

You need to use the `important`, and also reload browser using f5 so that browser don't cache.